# Get number of threads (defined via BlazeMeter) in a thread group from the setup thread group (jmeter)

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have a JMeter test plan which performs a simple action once. When I upload the test to BlazeMeter, I can then choose the number of threads I want for my thread group and run the test.

The problem I am having is that my test setup needs to know how many threads the thread group will have. To make things clearer, here is a simple representation of the test plan:

```
setUp Thread Group
  needs to know the number of threads in the below thread group
Thread Group
  The number of threads for this thread group is determined via BlazeMeter test configuration
```

Within the non-setup thread group, I can dynamically get the number of threads assigned via BlazeMeter, but I can't find any way of getting this number from within the setup thread group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the following [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
def numberOfThreads = ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads()
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter get number of threads in thread group]

The approach is environment-agnostic so you can use it anywhere. It may be more handy to use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like: `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads(),)}`

[image: Groovy Function Number of Threads]

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: That will return the number of threads in the setup thread group. I want the number of threads in the non-setup thread group.

Comment: Your comment answers my question so I will mark your answer as accepted. Perhaps it would be best if you edited the comment into your answer.

Comment: If you're interesting, I have also posted a follow-up question concerning the same problem in the case where the number of threads is defined in the thread group properties rather than in BlazeMeter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504273/get-number-of-threads-in-a-thread-group-from-the-setup-thread-group-jmeter